# Json filemtime error

Tags: php, json, yii

I need to write in a JSON file the last modified date of a list of directories and files, but I can't make this work, here is some code:

```
$dir = Yii::app()->basePath.'/../uploads';
        $objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
        $date = date('d-m-Y');
        $i=0;
        foreach($objects as $name => $object){
            print_r($i);
            $resultado = array(
                'fecha' => $date,
                'archivo' => $objects->getFilename(),
                'ruta'=>$objects->getPathname(),
                'modificacion' => filemtime($name), 
            );
            $i++;
            echo CJSON::encode($resultado);
            print_r("</br>");
        }
```

I need 'modificacion', I also tried:

```
$objects->getMtime();
$objects::getMtime();
$object->getMtime();
$object::getMtime();
$name->getMtime();
$name::getMtime();

filemtime($name);
filemtime($objects);
filemtime($object);
```

**ERRORS:**

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method RecursiveIteratorIterator::getMTime()
```

Thanks!

Comment: `filemtime('/path/to/file')` is what you want. You can't pass your iterator object to stat() and its related functions. They expect a filepath. They haven't got a clue what to do with your object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `filemtime` on the file name, not the key that maps to the iterator element.

Something like this:

```
 filemtime(realpath($objects->getPathname().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$objects->getFilename()));
```

That uses [realpath](https://www.php.net/realpath) to correct for things like extra slashes..